# Adding a column to a data frame based on certain criteria?

Tags: r

Assuming the following data frame:

```
df <- (data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3"),
                               Drink = c("Cola", "Pepsi", "Fanta")))
```

Output:

```
     ID  Drink
1     1   Cola        
2     2  Pepsi      
3     3  Fanta
```

I then have another data frame that looks something like this:

```
df2 <- (data.frame(Drink = c("Cola", "Fanta", "Cola", "Pepsi", "Pepsi")))

     Drink
1     Cola        
2    Fanta
3     Cola
4    Pepsi
5    Pepsi
```

I would like to create an extra column in this data frame that contains the IDs corresponding to whatever drink it specified in the row (based on the IDs in the first data frame (df)). So that the outcome looks like this:

```
     ID  Drink
1     1   Cola        
2     3  Fanta
3     1   Cola
4     2  Pepsi
5     2  Pepsi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R only you can do the following.
Note that in order to get the original order of `df2`, you will need to order `df2$Drink` and then invert the process.

```
inx <- order(df2$Drink)
merge(df, df2)[order(inx), 2:1]
#  ID Drink
#1  1  Cola
#3  3 Fanta
#2  1  Cola
#4  2 Pepsi
#5  2 Pepsi
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, this merge function seems to ruin my later functions, so I'm not sure if I'm able to implement this. Isn't there a simple VLOOKUP feature that you know of instead?

Comment: Try `df$ID[match(df2$Drink, df$Drink)]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `left_join` or `inner_join` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% left_join(df, by="Drink")

# Drink ID
# 1  Cola  1
# 2 Fanta  3
# 3  Cola  1
# 4 Pepsi  2
# 5 Pepsi  2
```